# syntax to constrain the files in a directory

Tags: java, python

I am using the (Unix) filesystem to manage files in a project and wish to constrain what files can occur in what directories. For example

```
myfile/
    manifest.xml
    images/
        figure1.png
        figure2.png
    data/
        file1.csv
        file2.csv
```

I want to write a (declarative) specification that asserts that there must be a `myfile` directory, that it has a child file `manifest.xml`, and child directories `images/`, with an arbitrary number of children of form `figure\d+.png` and so on.

My question, which I hope is not too general for SO, is are there Java or Python libraries for managing constraints on directory contents? (The problem is quite similar to using XML Schemas for validating child occurrence, and this could be a rather crude approach).

Comment: You can try with Maven plugin `Maven Enforcer Rules`, where during some life-cycle, can check if all rules meet requerements [https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/)

Comment: @Valijon that's a very useful start. Can I call the Maven plugin from Java? Could you write it as an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, enforcer rules (standard), does not allow regex to check files to exist/not exist. They offer to write [Custom rule checker](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html).

Answer (score 0):

you could use for each file an assertion in Python

```
import os
assert os.path.exists("images/figure1.png")
```

Comment: That's effectively what I am doing with Java `file.exists()` - the logic gets very spread out.

Comment: You could also put the files in one list and iterate over the list. Or write the filenames in a config file and generate the list from the config file.

Comment: That's roughly what I am starting to do at present. I am asking whether there is an agreed syntax, and hopefully libraries, for this